# How to compute a variable inside a matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, controls, transfer, eigenvalue

I have a `2x2` matrix of `[ 1 2; k 3]`,

and `k` is integer between `[0,5]`.

I want to plot the eigenvalues of this matrix as a function of `k` in the range of `[0,5]`.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at this:

```
   figure();  
   hold on;      
   for k = 0:5  
        plot (ones(2, 1)*k, eig([ 1 2; k 3]), 'o');   
   end
   grid on;
   xlabel('k'), ylabel('eigenvalue');
```

[image]

Comment: thank you for answering. I have two more question. 1) how do you set incremental values of k ( in this case you have 0.5 in the interval)?

Comment: 2), in your 4 line, you have 'ones(2,1)*k', if my matrix is 3x3, do I change the to 'ones(3,1)*k'? thank you very much

Comment: @user3222184 to change `xtick` after xlabels you can use `set(gca, 'xtick', [0:5]);`. If you have 3 resulting eigenvalues , than you need `ones(3,1)*k`.